# Force Netgear DG834GT LAN Speed/Duplex

Tags: router, lan

I have a Netgear DG834GT as my ADSL2+ modem & router, connected to a Netgear WNHDE111 wireless bridge. They've autonegotiated to 10Mbps rather than 100Mbps. I'm using brand new Cat6 cables so that's not the issue.

I came across [this article](http://nomido.xtreemhost.com/nghid.htm) which suggests how to force the connection to 100Mbps, but that's not for the T model which must have a different chip (`/proc/sys/dev` contains `ath/` and `wifi0/`)

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried with Cat5e cables too - same result. Connected my laptop to both devices independently and they both autonegotiate correctly. It's literally just when these two are connected to each other that they can't agree. Anyone know of how to force EITHER to 100Mbps full?